# Reduce stuck on Hadoop Pipes 1.1.2 (java.io.IOException: Bad command code: 48)

Tags: c++, hadoop, pipe, reduce

Good morning everyone,

I'm working on a full cluster running Hadoop Pipes 1.1.2 and I found these errors for very long jobs:

```
2013-07-24 06:13:55,058 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.BinaryProtocol: java.io.IOException: Bad command code: 48
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.BinaryProtocol$UplinkReaderThread.run(BinaryProtocol.java:157)
```

(this one in one node)

```
2013-07-24 06:18:03,472 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.BinaryProtocol: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.BinaryProtocol$UplinkReaderThread.readObject(BinaryProtocol.java:180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.BinaryProtocol$UplinkReaderThread.run(BinaryProtocol.java:132)
```

(this one in the rest that perform reduce tasks)

This is my reducer code. I use the map in there to sort by a secondary key inside the string, any performance improvements are also welcome!

```
void ACEReducer::reduce(HadoopPipes::ReduceContext& context) {
    string fragmento, instante, contenido;
    size_t pos;

    string fichero = string();
    map<string, string> resultados;

    // Ordena la lista de valores para escribirlos conforme al instante simulado (map se encarga de la ordenacon)
    int nValores = 0;
    while (context.nextValue()) {
        fragmento = context.getInputValue();
        pos = fragmento.find("\t", 0);

        if (pos == string::npos) {
            cerr << "ERROR - Valor erroneo en Reduce." << endl;
        } else {
            instante = fragmento.substr(0, pos);
            contenido = fragmento.substr(pos+1, string::npos);

            resultados.insert(pair<string&, string&>(instante, contenido));
        }

        nValores++;
        if (nValores % 10 == 0) {
            context.progress();
        }
    }

    // Concatena los resultados ordenados y los emite para escritura.
    nValores = 0;
    for (map<string, string>::iterator it=resultados.begin(); it!=resultados.end(); it++){
        nValores++;
        if (nValores % 10 == 0) {
            context.progress();
        }
        fichero += it->second;
    }
    context.emit(context.getInputKey(), fichero);
}
```

The code that is throwing the IOException is in the run() function in the Java BinaryProtocol; it can be found [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/pipes/BinaryProtocol.java.html) in line 120. The NegativeArraySizeException is thrown somewhere between lines 133 and 149; my guess is that `int numBytes = WritableUtils.readVInt(inStream);` is higher than INT_MAX but I don't know how to fix it.

HDFS looks healthy in all of the nodes, with only ~3% used. I'm using very robust nodes, with at least 64GB of RAM.

I've searched for this issue and I haven't found any hints, so any help is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Río